Why am I frequently asked for access to my Local Network since upgrading to Sequoia?
I recently upgraded to macOS 15, and ever since then, macOS randomly asks me to grant an app access to my local network.
The list of apps I see in "Privacy & Security" include:

VSCode
Google Chrome
Signal
Docker Desktop

…but I was asked for more apps than those listed there. I didn't grant any access, and I am really annoyed by this because it leads to notification fatigue.
Is there any reason why all of the sudden, I am frequently prompted to grant such access?
(For more context, I skipped Sonoma and went straight from macOS 13 to macOS 15)

It seems clear it’s your choice of apps that trigger this prompt. Is it unclear why they are running? Each prompt should be a direct response to your steps you take and your choices to select what you’re running on the OS.

While it's highly annoying, I admit (the iOS-ification of macOS), what is VSCode doing that the alert would pop?  That'd be concerning to me.  I can understand it (the pop) for Docker Desktop on the Mac.

It's an OS15 issue. I "get" that it's to improve security. However, I find it rather infuriating that every time Chrome is launched I have to go in and once again allow it to connect to the local network. The settings don't stick. If they stuck it'd be no big deal , but each and every time having to give permission is just poor design by someone, either Apple or Google.

@Scott Have you double-checked the "Privacy & Security" list of apps? If you tick Chrome there, does the setting stick?

@awendt Yes I go into Privacy> Accessibility > Local Network and give Chrome access. My point is I must do that at every boot. It doesn't "stick" across reboots. And, although visually  it's on after a reboot, I have to toggle it off, then back on for it to actually allow Chrome LAN access again.

The answer is here.
"In iOS 14 or later and iPadOS 14 or later, any app that wants to interact with devices on your network must ask for permission the first time it tries to browse your local network.
The app developer can customise the message to explain why the app would like access. For example, a game may want to find and connect to other players on the same network. Or a streaming app may be looking for a connected display.
Apps that access your local network can collect information about nearby devices in order to determine which networks you join and when. This information could be used to create a profile of you.
Tap Allow to grant the app access to your local network.
If you don’t want to allow access, or if it’s not clear to you why the app needs access, you can tap Don’t Allow. The app can still use the internet or interact with the local network using a system service, such as AirPrint, AirPlay, AirDrop or HomeKit."
(Text shamelessly lifted from the Apple Support page linked above.)

That article is about iOS and iPadOS, but the question is about macOS.

Same mechanism at work. I'll try to find a macOS specific page and fix it.

All the searching I've done the past half hour points to this iOS and iPadOS page at Apple Support. I never provide links to Reddit or other non-Apple sources unless absolutely necessary. If anybody reading this can find an Apple Support page which addresses this mechanism for macOS, please put the link in a comment or edit my answer.

According to TN3179: Understanding local network privacy, “local network privacy“ was added in macOS 15. There is also a link to WWDC 2024 Session 10123 which might be helpful.
